# Hair all goes weird once I change the mesh

Tags: modeling, hair

I have made this character, and I want to seperate the helmate from the body.
But soon as I delate, seperate, modify the helmate, the hair just all goes wild.
(Half of them would move to different place)

I used the body to make hair directly.

Someone save me please.[image: Hair all stuck on foot once removed helmate]

Comment: are this particles or a mesh?

Comment: The hairs are made of particles, this is Blender render

Comment: How can I add another picture to this site?

Comment: Oh no, her wig fell off! (0.0) You can upload your .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) . You can prepare a simplified version if the file is large or if you don't want to post all of your model, as long as the .blend illustrates the problem. Welcome to BSE!

Comment: I used another meterial for the hat to make it transparent, So this doesn't bother me right now. Thanks for all the helps

Answer (score 2):

It's easy before going into edit mode go to particle system disconnect all hair system by clicking on "disconnect hair"
Edit your mesh and reconnect hair
NOTE: - if you have activated children of hair then first connect the hair and re-activate children 
To re-activate Children: - go to children tab in particle group and click on "none" Then click on 'simle' or 'interpolated' by your choice.

Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Really thanks, this totally works for me. Solves everything.